# Toolbar doesn't flip the custom navigation icon arrow when switching to right-to-left layouts(Arabic)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, right-to-left

I am using right to left support for my app. I have a custom arrow set to toolbar as the navigation icon. When I switch to arabic language, everything aligns to right including the toolbar custom navigation arrow. But the problem is the custom navigation icon is not flipping, that is it should be pointing to the right instead of left(default). This works fine with the default indicator if I dont specify any navigation icon. Have anyone encountered this?

Any solution?

Here is my code for the toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:logo="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        >
```

in Activity

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_venue_filter);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Please care to explain the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the `Drawable`, not so much the Toolbar.
Try with:

```
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setAutoMirrored(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on android API 21+, you can just flip your icon by adding android:autoMirrored="true" to your vector icon or layer-list XML icon, this will alleviate the hasle of adding it to every toolbar manually, but if you want to support 21- versions you will have to go with the accepted answer.